# Why git subtree merge doesn't delete files?

Tags: git, merge, git-subtree

I have one branch ('other') attached as subtree to another ('master'). When I perform subtree merge from 'other' to 'master' it doesn't delete files which were deleted in 'other'.

Steps to reproduce on a clean repo:

```
$ touch master.txt
$ git add master.txt
$ git commit -m 'Initial master'
[master (root-commit) e2f5ffd] Initial master
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 master.txt
$ git checkout --orphan other
Switched to a new branch 'other'
$ touch other.txt
$ git add other.txt
$ git status
On branch other

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   master.txt
        new file:   other.txt
$ git commit -m 'Initial other'
[other (root-commit) 408ee95] Initial other
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 master.txt
 create mode 100644 other.txt
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git read-tree --prefix=other/ -u other
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   other/master.txt
        new file:   other/other.txt
$ git commit -m 'Other subtreed'
[master f9ba0db] Other subtreed
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 other/master.txt
 create mode 100644 other/other.txt
$ git checkout other
Switched to branch 'other'
$ git rm master.txt
rm 'master.txt'
$ git commit -m 'master.txt removed'
[other 1feef18] master.txt removed
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 master.txt
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git merge --squash -s subtree --no-commit other
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

So after merge of deleted file - there is nothing to commit. Is it correct behavior? And how to make merge with deleted files?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to merge subtree to have everything merged is:

```
git merge -s recursive -Xsubtree=other --no-commit other
```

So, it is without --squash and has a little different form (from git v2).

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I've got files that have been added by subtree merge and later once deleted your command does not delete them. It does correctly bring in the rest of the changes

Comment: @Glaz Did you find a solution to this issue? I am also facing this.